# cannot resolve method value?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

```
public class week2 {
    public static int numbers(int x, int y) {
        int value = x - y;
        System.out.println("Value is " + value + ".");
        return value;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numbers(20,10);
        if(value == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("yo");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("whatsup");
        }

    }
}
```

Why does the line if(value == 1) show the error that value cannot be resolved? Didn't I mention that value = x-y in my method? edit: ahh thank you guys I did not know that you can't access value outside the method

Comment: Because the variable is defined in the scope of your numbers method and it's not accessible from another method. Define it as a static member of your class and it would solve your issue.

Comment: you should store the value returned from numbers method in a variable and use that in your if condition.

Answer (score 2):

The `value` is a method variable in the numbers(int x,int y) method,which is not accessible outside this method.And this method will return a int which you are not storing into any variable name `value` in your `main` method.
       So,You need to change your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = numbers(20,10);
        if(value == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("yo");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("whatsup");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

value is a local variable in your function and since it is local it's not identified out of the function in the same class or another class so you must declare a variable in the main void to bound the value of value.